# Why is Windows System Image Backup so fast?

Tags: windows-10, backup

I create a daily system image backup of my client PC to our server:
[image: backup schedule]

As you can see in the screen shot, backup starts at 18:00 **and finishes two minutes later**. I also confirmed this by looking at the Microsoft/Windows/Backup/Operational event log:

```
Date/Time            Event ID  Message
31.05.2017 18:00:32     1      The backup operation has started.
31.05.2017 18:02:52     4      The backup operation has finished successfully.
31.05.2017 18:02:52    14      The backup operation has completed.
```

The date and time on the backup files on the server also look right:

[image: files]

As you can see in the screen shot, my main partition has ~378 GB worth of data. There is **no way** my 1 Gigabit network connection can transfer that much data in two minutes.

Is my backup broken or does Windows 10 have some very smart "incremental backup" algorithm, which just renames the folder on the backup share and "patches" the vhdx file with the changes?

Comment: PS: I also noticed that the folder is called `Backup 2017-05-31 160009` rather than `... 180009`, but  I guess that's because my time zone is currently UTC+2 (Central European Daylight Savings Time).

Comment: I think it might be because of how the backup process uses volume shadow copy and incremental algorithm?

Comment: BTW, if you suspect the backup is incomplete, **test it**. A software development company for which I worked had to restore source code, only to find that all available backups were faulty.